# Division by Zero - why does it not equal the original sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A little quirk in Mathematics is the wonderful value - $0$ (Zero).

The problem I have is the entire concept of "Cannot divide by zero" or "Divide by zero" error.  I would like to challenge this and perhaps gain a better understanding as to why this results in an error rather than the original sum as the main value.

### Example:

> If I have $100$ apples, and give them to $0$ people. How many apples are left?

*Results in the equation*: **$n - (n / d)$**

> $100 - ( 100 / 0 )$

### The correct answer is:

> You would have $100$ apples left since there was no one to give them to!

---

The premise, is that there are still $100$ apples that need to be accounted for, so where did they go?   If you gave $100$ apples to $1$ person, then you would have $0$ apples:   $100 - (100 / 1)$

In these cases, the total apples remain consistent, however if the result of the sub-equation:   $100 / 0$  results in an error, then the equation fails, and the solution can not be discovered using mathematics - which doesn't make any sense since the apples never went anywhere.

Why must any number divided by zero result in an error?  Wouldn't a better way to handle this to be a symbol or something to allow the calculation to continue but infer that the value did not change position/hands?

How could something like this realistically be proven in conventional mathematics that $100$ apples still exist - and that they didn't 'error' out of existence?

Comment: I think that this was the same doubt Ramanujan would have had in school.

Comment: @Rohan - perhaps.  I don't recall reading anything about it in his works.  perhaps unpublished, or internal speculation while busy on other issues ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the sense of the division you're using. In calculus it is not possible to divide by zero, but in this case you're using the division of number theory. In the number theory your definition of division is using the division equation: if $a,b$ are integers, then $a=bq+r$ for $q,r$ integers, and $r$ is the residue. If $r=0$, then we say that $a$ is divisible by $b$. In this case you have $100=0\cdot k+ 100$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, so $r=100$ and let's you the answer you said.

Comment: Interesting.  I was using the apple scenario to clearly demonstrate the problem, and yes, as you noted, division by zero also fails in calculus. It is  a rule that applies to all mathematics. The unusual part of this rule I have trouble agreeing with, is the destruction of the original value to divide. If you have 1.3414 particles and divide by 0, conventional math leaves you with no pi, and an error. The pi, still exists, but is no longer represented, thus no further calculations can be done.

Answer (score 2):

In formal mathematics, we don't define division using apples. It's a useful analogy to explain what division is to grade schoolers. We can do computations like $13 \div 5 = 2~r3$. Or once they get more advanced, we can say $13 \div 5 = 2 \frac{3}{5}$. But what how do you explain $-3.2 / 1.6 = -2$ with apples?

Instead, we define division using multiplication. First, we claim that, for each non-zero number $x$, there is another number $\overline{x}$ (just making up notation here, this isn't standard or anything), such that $x \times \overline{x} = 1$. To divide $a$ by $b$, we multiply $a$ by $\overline{b}$. This should mesh with what you already know; $\overline{x}$ is just $1/x$.

But why can't we define $\overline{0}$? Does anything stop us? It turns out that allowing any kind of inverse for zero will result in catastrophy! Say that $\overline{0}$ exists:
$$ 0 = 0 \times 1 = 0 \times (0 \times \overline{0}) = (0 \times 0) \times \overline{0} = 0 \times \overline{0} = 1 $$

(Note that the second and last steps come from the definition of $\overline{x}$.) We really don't want $0 = 1$, so this is a red flag that we cannot define $\overline{0}$ in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: What would you think of the concept along the lines of $n$/$0$ = $\overline{x}$$n$ , where $\overline{x}$ is symbolic representation of a 3rd state for the number.  It is not positive or negative, but it represents it does exist still ( also $\overline{x}$ is not standard, just using your concept as a potential candidate to describe the position )

Comment: I don't know what $x$ is here. But by my definition of division, I know that $n/0 = n \overline 0$.

Comment: Correct.  (i clarified the definition of $\overline{x}$ ).   Given any number divided by zero (technically all math boils down to addition), the value $n$ when divided by zero, instead of an error, the possibility of a 3rd representation. (Something other than + - )  as it is proven that any number divided by zero is consistent. The 3rd representation would annotate the existence of the original number given that nothing happens to it (so apples are not handed out, but they still exist - sorry for primary school analogy)

Comment: If $n/0=n\overline x$, then multiply the right side by $x$. Depending on how you evaluate it, you'll get either $0$ or $n$ (the argument will look a lot like the one in my post). So this suggests $n=0$ for all $n$, and that's certainly wrong. There is no way to define 1/0 in such a way as to get a well-behaved number.

Comment: Even a modulus type division results in an error (  $n mod 0$ )

Comment: I am speaking of using it as a new operator.   So   +, -, and a 3rd.   For example:   $-9 / 3 = -3$    so would be  $n / 0 =$ `new operand other than positive or negative that considers the value` $n$ `still exists without modification - it hasn't moved` $n$  .   so end result on right side would be  (3rd state neither positive or negative)$n$. The 3rd state could apply to inverse as well. any multiplication to 3rd state of 0 has no impact.

Comment: Interestingly enough, you can define mod 0 meaningfully. The appropriate generalization of mod is as an equivalence relation. We say $a$ and $b$ are equivalent mod $n$ iff $a - b = kn$ for some $k$ (i.e., they differ by a multiple of $n$). So if $a$ and $b$ are equivalent mod 0, that must mean they're equal. So $n$ mod 0 is just $n$.

Comment: That is true. Modulus formula can be represented, but when 0 is brought in as the divisor, it fails under current mathematics.  I just feel this is a limit which may have a solution as simple as increasing the complexity of mathematics by adding a 3rd state so the original data is not lost when these divisions occur (and they do a lot)  :)  Just an idea, I could be wrong of course. If we can progress into 3 state math then that could open boundaries. We are measuring a 3 dimensional universe with boolean values ( positive or negative ).

Comment: Okay, as for your operand thing, that doesn't let you escape. There's no well-behaved thing you can assign the result of $n/0$. Whatever it is, call it $f(n,0)$. We expect that $f(ab, 0) = a \times f(b, 0)$, and $f(0, 0) = 1$, because that's how division works. But then $1 = f(0, 0) = f(0 \times 1, 0) = 0 \times f(1, 0) = 0$. No matter what $f$ is, you have to break something.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Consider the @ (to keep it simplified) as the 3rd state (unmoved).    $100 / 0 = @100$  .   Now a couple of rules would apply to that state. One idea may be any operation with that state involving 0 resorts the state back to it's original value, or something more strict.  Such that  $100 / 0 = @100$ , then $100 = @100(0)$ , thus $100 = 100$  which is true.